# IF I have use antd4 Form Component,should I use Formik?

Tags: reactjs, antd, formik

as the title ,Formmik and antd Form all do the same thing :

1 validation
2 data-binding
3 error messages

formik https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/overview

antd Form https://ant.design/components/form-cn/

do they have the same functions?

Comment: Could you clarify your question?

Answer (score 6):

Both Formik & Antd Form provides similar functionality to manage form validation & error handle, form state variables, etc.

If you would like to use AntDesign Component UI for your project, I recommend to use Antd Form itself for your form (state, validation, error handle, etc). **You don't need Formik when you use Antd.**

If you would like to use other UI Libraries like Material-ui, semantic-ui, etc or to use your own customized UI, you should use Formik.